# Can you delete a project on SourceForge?

Tags: sourceforge

Just as the title says, can you delete a project on [SourceForge](http://sf.net)?

Comment: Have you seen [this wiki](http://sourceforge.net/apps/trac/sourceforge/wiki/Removing%20a%20project)?

Comment: Looks like you just need to create a ticket: https://sourceforge.net/p/forge/documentation/How%20to%20Remove%20a%20Project/

Answer (score 11, accepted):

[From their wiki](http://sourceforge.net/p/easyhtml5/tracinst/Removing%20a%20project/):

> **Removing a Project**
>
> At SourceForge.net, we feel a commitment to ensuring the long-term availability of the Open Source code released by the projects we host. We will weigh requests for project removal against the community value of leaving the project intact.
>
> When we receive a [request for project removal](https://sourceforge.net/p/forge/site-support/new/), we consider the following:
>
> - Has the project been registered less than 90 days? If so, the project will not be removed.
> - Has the project released files? If not, we will honor the removal request.
> - Does the request include legal justification, such as mention of a DMCA violation, trademark infringement or Terms of Service abuse problem related to the project? If it does, we consider this on a case-by-case basis.
> - Has the project merged with another project on SourceForge.net? If the project has been merged and all project materials ([CVS/Subversion](http://sourceforge.net/apps/trac/sourceforge/wiki/What%20is%20Source%20Code%20Management?) repository data, mailing lists, file releases) have been moved to the new project, we'll honor the removal request.
> - Projects which have moved to another hosting provider are typically retained at SourceForge.net (though you can make a note on the project web site and project summary page directing users to the new home) for sake of retaining materials of historical value.
> - Projects that are moving to closed source do not qualify for removal.

Comment: So basically if you have written content that is valuable to the community, regardless if you want to get rid of it, it is there to stay, unless of course it is some kind of plagiarism or being moved to another location on the site.

Comment: WTF sourceForge ! , I can't remove my own project, and you keep sending users viruses and maleware on my files !

Comment: @AmrLotfy exactly my problem. They should check if it has been moved to another (less evil) provider and honor the project owner's request. 'Historical value' my foot. I don't want anything I write to be bundled up in adware because of 'historical value', and I have a copyright on code I write - SF.net does not.

Comment: @Wyatt8740: "I have a copyright on code I write - SF.net does not" - by placing your code under an open source license, you have, in most cases, explicitly granted others the right to redistribute your code.

Comment: @O.R.Mapper Sure, in unmodified form. An open source license could just as well be one saying "Here's the code, you may not modify this code or use it in your own projects", or specifically state that it "cannot be distributed alongside other software in binary or source form" and have it be technically "open source", just not "free software" in the Stallman sense. If they bundled my software with their adware crap, and implicated my hard work into their profit-milking, then they are defaming me and my project, and violating my license.

Comment: @Wyatt8740: All true, but unrelated to project deletion. The stance that it should be possible to completely remove a project because the "owner" says so was around long before the (now apparently discontinued, BTW) infamous practice of inserting the adware installer started, and it is ill-conceived in that the moment something is released with a right to redistribute, redistribution might be happening - which means that the owner has effectively given up and lost control over the artifact's redistribution. I meant to comment just on that aspect, I agree with your qualms about the installer.

Comment: @O.R.Mapper GPL only guarantees the right to redistribute source code, AFAICT.

Comment: @Wyatt8740: If that is the case, then that might imply an obligation to remove binaries, not an obligation to remove the entire project.

Comment: @O.R.Mapper Looks to me like I could DMCA my own project to remove it.

Comment: @Wyatt8740: Maybe you could, even if it might just work because no-one would bother to completely establish whether the claim is valid. In any case, I don't see what's the point of first granting usage and redistribution rights for something to the public, and then making that something artificially hard to access in the first place by removing one of its most visible copies.

Comment: @Wyatt8740: "GPL only guarantees the right to redistribute source code, AFAICT." - by the way, that is not correct. Section 6 of the GPL deals with redistributing compiled versions (called "object code" in the license) and starts with the words "You may convey a covered work in object code form under the terms of sections 4 and 5".

Comment: Yep, but I would consider it infringing to distribute it (wrapped in an installer, for instance) if it is being done under the guise of coming from the author, rather than prepared by SF.net.

Comment: @O.R.Mapper whoops, meant to reply to you. Anyway, I am aware of the clause. You have a case to make. However I would consider it defamation if they are packaging my works with their own stuff and claiming I made it.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, just go to the project page, select the "Metadata" option in the menu on the left of the page and then click on "Delete project". A popup will show up asking you to type "DELETE" in order to confirm your action. After that, your project will enter a deletion queue.